# How are steroid hormones secreted?

Tags: endocrinology

Peptide hormones for example tend to be secreted by Ca2+ mediated exocytosis following depolarisation and are secreted in vesicles. How are steroid hormones secreted and what stimulates their secretion? Please leave references if possible.

Comment: **Homework questions** and **trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). "*Homework*" is interpreted to mean any academic or other assignment, test preparation, or task given in relation to a class, educational setting, or self-learning.